# django: Using column value as mutex - updating column uniquely in django? (w/ SQL example)

Tags: django

Simplifying the problem down to its essence, I'd like to do this natively in django rather than embedding the sql:

```
UPDATE job SET state_id = 100
WHERE job.id = 1 and 0 in (select count(*) from job where state_id = 100);
```

This SQL statement will **atomically** update the state to 100 if and only iff there are currently 0 jobs in state 100.

Essentially I only want one job to be in state 100.

Can this be done natively in django?

Comment: While I'd still like to know if this kind of subquery is possible in django, I'm realizing this could be simplified greatly to simply a lock table for the resource I'm serializing the jobs against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have my own solution... This essentially locks ALL of the rows in the table until the transaction commits.  (Which isn't very desirable)

```
# X is the job id to uniquely put into state 100.

with transaction.commit_on_success()
    count = 0
    myjob = None
    for job in Job.objects.select_for_update().all():
        if job.state_id == 100:
            count +=1
        if job.id == X:
            myjob = job
    if count == 0 and myjob:
        myjob.state_id = 100
        myjob.save()
```

Alternatively, you could also create a lock table that tracks which job is in the unique state,

```
class StateLock(Model):
    # XXX: could add an expiration column, too.
    state = ForeignKey(State)
    locker = ForeignKey(Job, null=True)  # Use IntegerField until 
                                         # django bug 16715 is fixed!!
```

And use

```
# lock:
StateLock.objects.filter(state=100, locker=None).update(locker=job.id)

# unlock:
StateLock.objects.filter(state=100, locker=job.id).update(locker=None)
```

NOTE: The nullable foreign key is broken until django bug 16715 is fixed.  Otherwise the query generated is incorrect.  Substitute with a PositiveIntegerField.